# How to persist Firebase authdata after Force Quit (iOS)

Tags: ios, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using email + password authentication with Firebase for my app. Login works, and I use `observeAuthEventWithBlock` to check if a user is logged in - in order not to bring up the Login page. If I press the home button and open the app again, there is no problem. The problem I am having is if I force-quit the app. When I re-open, I have to log-in again.

Some notes about the setup before I show my login code.

- There is a LoginViewController - not embedded - built w/ Storyboard
- This is connected to a Navigation Controller
- Which is what the first screen is embedded in, and the rest of the app uses this Nav Controller.

Login code:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed() {
    let userEmail = emailTextField.text

    self.ref.authUser(self.emailTextField.text, password: self.passwordTextField.text, withCompletionBlock: { (error, auth) -> Void in

        guard error == nil else {
            if let errorCode = FAuthenticationError(rawValue: error.code) {
                switch (errorCode) {
                case .EmailTaken:
                    self.displayMessage("Email Error", theMessage: "This email is taken")
                case .InvalidEmail:
                    self.displayMessage("Email Error", theMessage: "This email is invalid")
                case .UserDoesNotExist:
                    self.displayMessage("User Error", theMessage: "A user account for email: \(userEmail!) does not exist")
                case .InvalidPassword:
                    self.displayMessage("Password Error", theMessage: "The password is incorrect")
                case .NetworkError:
                    self.displayMessage("Network Error", theMessage: "Seems like there's a problem with your internet connection")
                default:
                    return
                }
            }
            return //set Unknown Error Alert here
        }
        print("LOGGED IN: segue from loginButtonPressed")
        self.userLoggedIn = true
        print("user is logged in? \(self.userLoggedIn)")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginLocaleSegue", sender: self)
    })
}
```

Check if user is logged in - if so segue to navcon, pop it and display embedded View Controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if self.userLoggedIn.boolValue == true {

        ref.observeAuthEventWithBlock { (authData) -> Void in

            if authData != nil {

 let navCon: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
                self.presentViewController(navCon, animated: false, completion: nil)
                navCon.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
                print("user is authenticated: \(authData.providerData["email"] as! String)")

                print("segues from viewDidAppear")

            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

I've seen questions related to Firebase auth which state that Authdata is stored in Keychain by default, which causes problems with Authdata persisting even after deletion of app, but I'm experiencing the total opposite issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're not writing "self.userLoggedIn = true" to any database, so it makes sense that it continues being "True" while you have the app on idle, but once you close the application, it then becomes nil (no value), this is because it's just chilling in the background while the app is open, but not completely closed. Try writing this to your Firebase database, as outlined in this tutorial, and see if that helps.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/109706/firebase-tutorial-getting-started